# Gitpod to run a C hello world program

Tags: c, linux, visual-studio-code, ide, gitpod

I am new to C language but I use [Gitpod](https://www.gitpod.io/) for other languages. I would like to know how to run this simple "hello world" main.c program from the Gitpod interface step by step?

```
#include <studio.h>
void main(){
    printf("hello")
}
```

Many thanks !

Comment: `studio` -> `stdio.h`, `main()` must return an `int` and `printf()` needs a semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fixing the errors you can compile the code with `gcc main.c` and run the binary `a.out`.
Errors as already mentioned:

- `studio.h` -> `stdio.h`
- `...hello")` -> `...hello");`

Comment: Thanks Wulf Thimm. Errors in the code were not really the point for me at this moment. And how to run the code solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

after the printf("hello")
you should put ;

```
//like this
printf("hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it